# List Diffrent Text and Images Using ArrayList and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am trying to list different text and images in a list format with the RecyclerView at the moment it is showing the same text and images for all 5 rows how can I list different text and images in every row using the same layout file and adapter class or must I create a new layout + datalist + adapter class for every row I am new to java bit confused.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    ArrayList<DataList> dataList = new ArrayList<DataList>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {

        dataList.add(new DataList(

                "Ball Juggle (while standing)",
                "Hold",
                R.drawable.lt1,
                "+",
                "Tap",
                R.drawable.lt2
        ));
    }

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(dataList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<DataList> dataList;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public View view;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<DataList> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
   TextView title = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView desc = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView desc2 = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.desc2);
    TextView desc3 = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.desc3);
    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    title.setText(dataList.get(position).getTitle());
    desc.setText(dataList.get(position).getDesc());
    imageView.setImageResource(dataList.get(position).getImage());
    desc2.setText(dataList.get(position).getDesc2());
    desc3.setText(dataList.get(position).getDesc3());
    imageView2.setImageResource(dataList.get(position).getImage2());


}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
}
```

Data List

```
public class DataList {

String title;
String desc;
int image;
String desc2;
String desc3;
int image2;

public DataList(String title, String desc, int image, String desc2, String desc3, int image2) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
    this.desc2 = desc2;
    this.desc3 = desc3;
    this.image2 = image2;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getDesc2 () {
    return desc2;
}

public String getDesc3 () {
    return desc3;
}

public int getImage2 () {
    return image2;
}
}
```

Row Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title" />

<ImageView
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/desc" />

<TextView
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/desc2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/desc3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/desc2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/desc2" />

<ImageView
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/desc3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/desc3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Trying to do this but obviously code is wrong cause its only showing one row how must I edit this code

```
ArrayList<DataList> dataList = new ArrayList<DataList>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {

        dataList.add(new DataList(

                "France",
                "Russia",
                R.drawable.lt1,
                "America",
                "Europe",
                R.drawable.lt2
        ));
    }

    ArrayList<DataList2> dataList2 = new ArrayList<DataList2>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {

        dataList2.add(new DataList2(

                "South Africa",
                "Brazil",
                R.drawable.lt1,
                "New Zeland",
                "Pakistan",
                R.drawable.lt2
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> showing the same text and images for all 5 rows

Becuase here:

```
dataList.add(new DataList(
                "Ball Juggle (while standing)",
                "Hold",
                R.drawable.lt1,
                "+",
                "Tap",
                R.drawable.lt2
        ));
```

Creating all 5 objects of `DataList` class by passing same same values in  `DataList` class constructor.

Use different values which want to show in ListView rows for creating `DataList` class object.

**EDIT :**
Do it as:

**1.**  Create Array of items :

```
String[] strItem = {"Ball Juggle (while standing)","b","c","b","c"};
int[] intImageIds = {R.drawable.lt1,R.drawable.lt1,...};
```

**2.** In for loop create object of `DataList` class using `strItem` and `intImageIds` arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {
    dataList.add(new DataList(
            strItem[i],
            "Hold",
            intImageIds[i],
            "+",
            "Tap",
            R.drawable.lt2
    ));
}
```

Comment: @JacquesKrause: see my edit answer probably help you. let me know still facing any issue

Comment: Still struggling I am very very new to java I want this but obviously the code is wrong. see above